# Multiple ComboBoxEdit controls with same items

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, static, devexpress

I am working on a user control which contains a SpinEdit (numeric up-down) control and a ComboBoxEdit. The option selected in the combo-box provides a factor by which number in the SpinEdit is multiplied. At the moment, I have something like this:

```
public class MyUserControl : DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraUserControl 
{
    private static List<String> listItems;
    static MyUserControl() // Populate the list of options with the default options
    {
        listItems = new List<String?();
        listItems.Add("Option1");
        listItems.Add("Option2");
        listItems.Add("Option3");
    }

    public MyUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Add default options to the combo box
        foreach (String item in listItems)
        {
            this.cboBox.Properties.Items.Add(item);
        }
    }
}
```

That works fine (note that the above is simplified, in reality the static list is a static Dictionary which maps the strings to the multiplication factor) except that I want to allow the user to add custom options to `listItems` and have these appear on every instance of this user control in my application. That is why `listItems` is static, as my hope was to do `this.cboBox.Properties.Items = listItems;` so that any additions to `listItems` would appear on every control. However, the `Items` property is read-only so I cannot do that.

How can I go about ensuring every instance of my user control has the same set of options, even if these are changed? Having the static members fire an event when the user changes the option list might do the trick, but that seems a bit overkill for something that looks as simple as this. Does anyone have any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case is better to use `LookUpEdit` control instead of `ComboBoxEdit`. Just make some adjustments to it:

```
lookUpEdit1.Properties.ShowHeader = false;
```

You can use your `listItems` in that way:

```
lookUpEdit1.Properties.DataSource = listItems;
```

But there is some problem with `Dictionary` as `DataSource`. For `DataSource` you must use an collection that implements `IList`, `ITypedList` or `IBindingList` interface. So, you can convert your `Dictionary` to `List` or you can use this trick:

```
private static Dictionary<int, string> items;

//...

lookUpEdit1.QueryPopUp += lookUpEdit_QueryPopUp;
lookUpEdit2.QueryPopUp += lookUpEdit_QueryPopUp;

//...

private void lookUpEdit_QueryPopUp(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    var lookUpEdit = (LookUpEdit)sender;

    lookUpEdit.Properties.DataSource = null;
    lookUpEdit.Properties.DataSource = items;
}
```

But I think is better to use `List` instead of `Dictionary`.

Comment: That sounds like the way to go, thanks. I've changed it to a look-up-edit. However, I still can't get it to work. Maybe it is because, as I said in the O.P., in reality the static list is a static Dictionary (is the Values property of a dictionary the same object every time you ask for it, or does it construct a new collection to return?)

Comment: Thanks for the update. It is a dictionary though, so it needed to be `lookUpEdit.Properties.DataSource = items.Values`. Think I might try to change it into a List though to save the event handler code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the DevExpress controls (you might want to ask on their support forums), but in classic Windows comboboxes, the list is maintained inside the control. The Items property is a .Net wrapper that makes the internal structure easier to work with. So, it's not possible to assign the same data structure to each combobox. They have their own copy.

Your idea to have a publish/subscribe mechanism to what are now static lists seems like a reasonable solution.

If it were me, instead of having static stuff on the control class, I'd make that master list container a separate class and have a property on the control that takes an instance of that class. It'd make your overall architecture a bit more flexible and testable.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion on breaking out the static stuff into a seperate class. I've made those parts into a singleton class so it is available to all instances of my user control.